# C# FileSystemWatcher - multiple events

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-services

i create this windows service that when a file .txt/.csv appears in a specific folder, takes this file and put the first row in a db one time. the problem is that once the service starts, the event handler "handle" only 1 time the adding of file, in fact when i delete the file and try to put another one, the service doesn't add the data in the db and i have to restart it manually. the solution I need though is that this service, once started, remains active and create a filesystemwatcher(/eventhandler) that runs like the service and every time a new file is added it inserts the first row into the db

```
namespace myServiceDB_D1
{
public partial class ServiceD1 : ServiceBase
{
    public ServiceD1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Timer mainTimer = new Timer(); // name space(using System.Timers;)  

    public static FileSystemWatcher watcher;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
        mainTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(main);
        mainTimer.Interval = 2 * 1000; //Interval of 2sec
        mainTimer.AutoReset = false;
        //mainTimer.Enabled = true;
        mainTimer.Start();
    }

    private void main(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        mainTimer.Stop();
        mainTimer.Dispose();

        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\newData",
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
        };
        watcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
        watcher.Renamed += FileSystemWatcher_Renamed;
        watcher.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    

    public static void FileSystemWatcher_Changed(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = e.FullPath;
        DataTable imported_data = GetDataFromFile(path);
        if (imported_data == null) return;
        SaveImportDataToDatabase(imported_data);

    }

    private static DataTable GetDataFromFile(string path)
    {
        DataTable importedData = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {

                string[] headerColumns = header.Split(';');
                foreach (string headerColumn in headerColumns){
                    importedData.Columns.Add(headerColumn);
                }
               
                 string[] headerColumns = {"misura_durezza"};
                foreach (string headerColumn in headerColumns){
                    importedData.Columns.Add(headerColumn);
                }
                 
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("no file data");
                        return null;
                    }
                    
                    DataRow importedRow = importedData.NewRow();
                    importedRow[0] = line.ToString();
                    importedData.Rows.Add(importedRow);
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return importedData;
    }

    private static void SaveImportDataToDatabase(DataTable imported_data)
    {

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=controlmachine;Uid=root;Pwd=")) 
        {
            try
            {
                WriteToFile($"Connection to database");
                conn.Open();
                WriteToFile($"Connected to database");
                foreach (DataRow importRow in imported_data.Rows)
                {
                    
                    MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO temp_d1 (misura_durezza) VALUES (@misura_durezza)";


                    WriteToFile($"Creating query");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@misura_durezza", importRow["misura_durezza"]);

                    WriteToFile($"Executing query");
                   
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                WriteToFile($"Failed to insert into the database");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void FileSystemWatcher_Renamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteToFile($"File Renamed: {e.OldFullPath} renamed to {e.FullPath}");
    }
    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteToFile("Service is recalled at " + DateTime.Now);
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {

        WriteToFile("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    public static void WriteToFile(string Message)
    {
        string path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\serviceLog";
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
       
        string filepath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\serviceLog\\serviceLog_D1_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".txt";
        if (!File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.   
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Unrelated: Consider using a Logging Framework. It will make your life easier.

Comment: Why all that hassle with the timer?

Comment: Also, Disk I/O and Database I/O are expensive operations. You don't want to perform them in the event handler. I'd create a Blocking Queue and have a Thread block on it, waiting for input. Then I'd just enqueue file paths from the event handler and have the dedicated thread do file I/O and DB I/O. _Maybe_ alternatively I'd consider DataFlow. But this seems simple enough.

Comment: `importedRow[0] = line.ToString();` - `line` is already a string.

Comment: It might well be that your WriteToFile method fails. It is not guarded with a try / catch and it is possible to be called by different threads. So while thread 1 just opened the logfile for an Append, here comes Thread 2 trying to do the same. Do the logging framework or try to make that method thread safe.

Comment: @Maze, based on my test, it is best for to set enough time to give the windows service to complete the work. Try to set  mainTimer.Interval = 60 * 1000;

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug, you have subscribed to the same event two times.

```
 watcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
```

Comment: even if i delete this line the watcher continues to insert in the db only the first file created after the service start

Answer (score 0):

NotifyFilters.LastWrite catch up two events.

i changed it in

```
watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
    {
        Path = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\newData",
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName,
    };
```

and now it works